# single valued holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Do there exists singled valued analytic function $f(z)$ such that $$f(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-tz}\sqrt{\sin t} dt$$
More precisely, can we find domain $D$ such that the $f$ is single valued and analytic?

How to start this problem? How to determine the branch cut of this integral

The same question for function $[g(z)]^2=\frac{1-z}{1+z}$. I think $g$ can be made single valued in the upper unit disk. I m not sure. Thanks

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{\sin t}$ when $\sin t<0$?

Comment: What does single valued mean to you? What you seem to be asking appears contradictory to me.

Comment: However, if we replace $\sin t$ by $\left|\sin t\right|$, the integral can be computed in terms of ratios of $\Gamma$ functions and exponentials.

Comment: First you  need to clarify what you mean by $\sqrt{\sin t}$, as has been suggested. Then ask yourself this: Given $z$, how does the function $e^{tz}$ behave as $t\to+\infty$? For some $z$ it dies exponentially, for other $z$ it does not. What's the absolute value of $e^{tz}$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The question is exactly as it stated. What you said is exactly what I was thinking.